# How add to category "Custom Layout Update" through install/update script

Tags: layout, magento-1, custom, upgrade

How add to category **Custom Layout Update** through install/update script

This don't work:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);
$category->setCustomLayoutUpdate('some_update_there')->save();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**it may  be store issue ,magento is set value store wise**

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id); 
$category ->setStoreId(0); // 0 means store admin
$category->setCustomLayoutUpdate('some_update_there')->save();
```

Comment: Snx for help. Found in the table indicate the need store.

Answer (score 0):

Try please code for update the category tree:

```
$this->startSetup();

Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);
$category->setStoreId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$category->setPageLayout('some_update_there')
    ->save();

$this->endSetup();
```

Comment: page_layout is not an attribute which stores custom layout update content. custom_layout_update is the one which does that.